# keeping a html / php form from timing out

Tags: php, html, mysql, timeout, session-timeout

I have a rather long html / php form that I have users fill out and if it takes longer than my server allows max connection time, then it times out and they lose what they have filled out when the form does not submit correctly. The users log in through and a session cookie is created for credentials that go along with the mysql INSERT statement.

My question is would setting up an autosave keep that connection alive if it is communicating with the database on an autosave every half hour or so? Or is there a better way to do this? Mind you, it's not the save that takes too long and times out, it seems to be the inactivity with the database that causes the dropped connection.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: If you aren't uploading some file than a post won't need the max execution time (near 60 seconds normally). If your system need more time it can depend on a lot of things. Better check your system.

Comment: When the submit form is processed, new database connections are created, so it's probably not the DB. Check the cookie expirations and session timeout values.

Comment: Saving the form-in-progress is not a bad idea, especially if it will take some time to complete. Just be sure that a user can reload the page and pick up where they left off. To do that you'll need to include some kind of unique token in the URL to fetch the partially completed form. In any case, the max connection time should not be a factor here. The request should have produced the form and finished, then later a subsequent request would save it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a page which will keep connection live and send a hidden call through ajax after a periodic interval to keep session and other things alive while user is not interacting with the page.